# How do I assure that a module is loaded only if the script is running on Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, perl, module, perl-module

I have a Perl script that needs to run on both Windows and Linux. The problem is I need to `use` a Perl module that only applies to Windows.

I have tried the below, but it still includes thie `WindowsStuff` package.

```
use strict;
if ($^O eq 'MSWin32' ){
    use My::WindowsStuff;
}
use File::Basename;
use Getopt::Long;
...
...
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `use` takes effect at compile time, it doesn't respect the ordinary flow control of the code being compiled. 
In particular, putting a use inside the false branch of a conditional doesn't prevent it from being processed.

What you can do?

a) [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) import (run-time):

```
if( $^O eq 'MSWin32' ) {
   require My::WindowsStuff;
   My::WindowsStuff->import if My::WindowsStuff->can("import");
}
```

b) [`use if`](http://perldoc.perl.org/if.html) (compile-time):

```
use if $^O eq 'MSWin32', "My::WindowsStuff";
```